# what flavor of Regular expression being used in Wso2 esb 4.9.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Could anyone confirm which flavor of regular expression being used by wso2 esb 4.9.0 or others ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally, with some research I get to know "Java has it's own flavor for regular expression"
Documentation for all possible keyword or tokens can be found on the following  url https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html.